# Create a downloadable attachment from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file, download, mime

I'm getting varbinary data(file contents) from the DB along with the file name and mime type. Depending on how many files are there, I need to display links for those files on the web page. When the user clicks on a link, that file should get downloaded. Since the links will get created dynamically, I think i will have to call a client side function to handle the downloading. But I don't know how this can be done. On the server side(C#) we can use FileContentType, but how can this be achieved through JavaScript? Also, since I do not have a physical file and just it's contents, I will have to somehow create this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just create links to C# server-side actions that dynamically serve the contents.

Create an action in your controller that takes an ID of some sort and returns the file.  You can then use `<a>` tags that point directly to this action's URLs (with different IDs).  You don't need any Javascript.

Comment: could you elaborate a little?

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: create links to C# server side actions? I haven't done something like this before, so I may have a little difficulty getting the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. However, my project is a Web Application.

Comment: @neuDev33: Then use an ASHX (Generic Handler) with a querystring.